# If I want to edit a chrome extension browser action popup using jquery, where do I need to include jquery in the program to use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make an extension that gets an XMLrequest and takes the information and writes it to the browser action popup's html page. Is this possible?

Here's my manifest file

```
//manifest.json
"name":"myExtension",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon":"favicon.ico",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

My browser action popup html file:

```
<!--popup.html-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p class="add"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

And my script:

```
//popup.js

//Code up to this point gets xml info, I didn't include

var info = //string from xml request
$.(".add").html(info);
```

I see the Hello paragraph in the popup window, but never the info which should be in the add paragraph, and when I check the console, it tells me that the $ is undefined. How can I get jquery to work for me? I'm a relative newcomer to this so I'm sorry if this is really simple and I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points that are wrong

- The order of adding your scripts; it should be:

  ```
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  ```
- Your selector is wrong; it shouldn't be `$.(".add")` but `$(".add")`:

  ```
  $(".add").html(info);
  ```
- You need to wrap your jQuery commands into DOM ready/on load:

  ```
  $(function() {
    var info = //string from xml request
    $(".add").html(info);
  });
  ```

Also, you don't need to add the script to `content_scripts` if you don't going to use it there.
You have full access to your extensions resources from the background page and the popup.

Comment: Sorry I don't  understand how I could use `chrome.extension.getURL`, could you be a little more specific in what you mean by accessing it?

Comment: @RyanGibbons Sorry I was wrong, I updated my answer with correct details. It's tested this time :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add it to your manifest.json as such:

```
content_scripts": [
 {
  "js": ["jquery.js"]
 }
]
```

It will then auto include it.  I would put your popup.js in there as well after the jquery to ensure that jQuery is loaded first. so like:

```
"js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"]
```

Comment: That is for the content script. If I read OP correctly OP is talking about the popup in the / next to addressbar.

Comment: That's true, I haven't done a popup extension before so it may not work.  I assumed it would be the same.

Comment: @jefffan24 Yeah it's for the popup specifically, not a content script for the background page.

Comment: the only other thing I can recommend (And again probably won't work) is see if it will load jQuery from a CDN in the script tag.

I don't think it will but its worth a shot.